# Excel VBA pasting to multiple ranges

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to paste formula into multiple ranges. I actually have a long list of ranges I want to paste to. is there a way to loop through this list without having to write code for each range? i tried pasting the list of ranges into one line it's too long for one line

```
Range('LCM-00 (2)'!$J$57:$Y$57).copy
Range('LCM-00 (2)'!$J$57:$Y$57,'LCM-00 (2)'!$J$54:$Y$54,'LCM-00 (2)'!$K$50:$Y$50,'LCM-00 (2)'!$K$47:$Y$47,'LCM-00 (2)'!$AB$57:$AQ$57,'LCM-00 (2)'!$AB$54:$AQ$54,'LCM-00 (2)'!$AC$50:$AQ$50,'LCM-00 (2)'!$AC$47:$AQ$47,'LCM-00 (2)'!$AT$57:$BI$57,'LCM-00 (2)'!$AT$54:$BI$54,'LCM-00 (2)'!$AU$50:$BI$50,'LCM-00 (2)'!$AU$47:$BI$47,'LCM-00 (2)'!$BL$57:$CA$57,'LCM-00 (2)'!$BL$54:$CA$54,'LCM-00 (2)'!$BM$50:$CA$50,'LCM-00 (2)'!$BM$47:$CA$47,'LCM-00 (2)'!$CD$57:$CS$57,'LCM-00 (2)'!$CD$54:$CS$54,'LCM-00 (2)'!$CE$50:$CS$51,'LCM-00 (2)'!$CE$47:$CS$47,'LCM-00 (2)'!$J$42:$Y$42,'LCM-00 (2)'!$K$35:$Y$35,'LCM-00 (2)'!$K$32:$Y$32,'LCM-00 (2)'!$AB$42:$AQ$42,'LCM-00 (2)'!$AB$39:$AQ$39,'LCM-00 (2)'!$AC$35:$AQ$35,'LCM-00 (2)'!$AC$32:$AQ$32,'LCM-00 (2)'!$AT$42:$BI$42,'LCM-00 (2)'!$AT$39:$BI$39,'LCM-00 (2)'!$AU$35:$BI$35,'LCM-00 (2)'!$AU$32:$BI$32,'LCM-00 (2)'!$BL$42:$CA$42,'LCM-00 (2)'!$BL$39:$CA$39,'LCM-00 (2)'!$BM$35:$CA$35,'LCM-00 (2)'!$BM$32:$CA$320,'LCM-00 (2)'!$CD$42:$CS$42,'LCM-00 (2)'!$CD$39:$CS$39,'LCM-00 (2)'!$CE$35:$CS$35,'LCM-00 (2)'!$CE$32:$CS$32,'LCM-00 (2)'!$J$28:$Y$28,'LCM-00 (2)'!$J$25:$Y$25,'LCM-00 (2)'!$K$21:$Y$21,'LCM-00 (2)'!$AB$28:$AQ$28,'LCM-00 (2)'!$AB$25:$AQ$25,'LCM-00 (2)'!$AC$21:$AQ$21,'LCM-00 (2)'!$AC$18:$AQ$18,'LCM-00 (2)'!$AT$28:$BI$28,'LCM-00 (2)'!$AT$25:$BI$25,'LCM-00 (2)'!$AU$21:$BI$21,'LCM-00 (2)'!$AU$18:$BI$18,'LCM-00 (2)'!$BL$28:$BI$28,'LCM-00 (2)'!$BL$25:$BI$25,'LCM-00 (2)'!$BM$21:$CA$21,'LCM-00 (2)'!$BM$18:$CA$18,'LCM-00 (2)'!$CD$28:$CS$28,'LCM-00 (2)'!$CD$25:$CS$25,'LCM-00 (2)'!$CE$21:$CS$21,'LCM-00 (2)'!$CE$18:$CS$18,'LCM-00 (2)'!$J$14:$Y$14,'LCM-00 (2)'!$J$11:$Y$11,'LCM-00 (2)'!$K$7:$Y$7,'LCM-00 (2)'!$K$4:$Y$4,'LCM-00 (2)'!$AB$14:$AQ$14,'LCM-00 (2)'!$AB$11:$AQ$11,'LCM-00 (2)'!$AC$7:$AQ$7,'LCM-00 (2)'!$AC$4:$AQ$4,'LCM-00 (2)'!$AT$14:$BI$14,'LCM-00 (2)'!$AT$11:$BI$11,'LCM-00 (2)'!$AU$7:$BI$7,'LCM-00 (2)'!$AU$4:$BI$4,'LCM-00 (2)'!$BL$14:$CA$14,'LCM-00 (2)'!$BL$11:$CA$11,'LCM-00 (2)'!$BM$7:$CA$7,'LCM-00 (2)'!$BM$4:$CA$4,'LCM-00 (2)'!$CD$14:CS$14,'LCM-00 (2)'!$CD$11:CS$11,'LCM-00 (2)'!$CE$7:CS$7,'LCM-00 (2)'!$CE$4:CS$44).select
range.xlpaste
```

not sure how to do this. I'm a beginner. TIA

Comment: Can you rephrase your question?  I've read it twice and it's still wooshing right over my head.

Comment: Whatever you're trying to do, which is unclear, that is not the way to do it. Have you tried writing formulas and then filling down?

Answer (score 1):

I hope I have got your goal right - Copy a source range and paste to multiple ranges across the same workbook.

You can do it with a loop and `Split()`, consider below:
[image: initial]

- `A1:G1` has a fixed value from `10` to `70`
- `A2` has formula `=A1+1`
- `A3` has formula `=A1*2`

The code below will copy the range `A2:A3` to multiple ranges, separated by comma in a text string `"B2:B3,C2:C3,D2:D3,E2:E3,F2:F3,G2:G3"`. You can put Full Range text like `'Sheet2'!B2:B3,...`.

Code to paste the ranges:

```
Option Explicit

Sub PasteRanges()
    Dim oRngSrc As Range, oItem As Variant, sPasteTo As String

    Set oRngSrc = Range("A2:A3") ' Source Range to Copy From
    sPasteTo = "B2:B3,C2:C3,D2:D3,E2:E3,F2:F3,G2:G3"
    ' This works:
    oRngSrc.Copy Range(sPasteTo)
    ' If it complains about being too long, use below loop
    For Each oItem In Split(sPasteTo, ",")
        oRngSrc.Copy Range(oItem) ' Paste to oItem
    Next
End Sub
```

Result:
[image: Result]

---

Personally I don't recommend this approach, but this is what you asked.